# Rails+Capycabra+poltergeist NameError: uninitialized constant I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, phantomjs

I just started playing with Capycabra  and after execution my first Capy test, it fails with an error

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content I18n.t("form_input.item.item_s")
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant I18n
```

my test

```
#spec/features/test_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe 'accessibility of webpage' do
  it 'should access web page' do
    visit '/item/new'
    expect(page).to have_content I18n.t("form_input.item.item_s")
  end
end
```

I  tried explicitly include I18n module like `require 'i18n'` , but test fails with the result

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content I18n.t("form_input.item.item_s")
       expected #has_content?("translation missing: en.form_input.item.item_s") to return true, got false
```

My spec_helper.rb file

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Full Version of spec_helper: http://pastebin.com/qkANfu39

Apparently I need to include the module I18n into spec_helper, but no idea how it should be done.

I need your help guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working by including 'rails_helper' file into a test file.. The final version of a Capy test:

```
#spec/features/test_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'accessibility of webpage' do
  it 'should access web page' do
    visit '/item/new'
    expect(page).to have_content I18n.t("form_input.item.item_s")
  end
end
```